# Android studio unable to start after enabling virtualizaion

Tags: android-studio

Afte enabling virtualzation on my HP Probook 6460b ( and disabling later), trying ./studio.sh in the bin folder is unable to start Studio and shows these lines:

-Xmixed           mixed mode execution (default)
-Xint             interpreted mode execution only
-Xbootclasspath:<directories and zip/jar files separated by :>
set search path for bootstrap classes and resources
-Xbootclasspath/a:<directories and zip/jar files separated by :>
append to end of bootstrap class path
-Xbootclasspath/p:<directories and zip/jar files separated by :>
prepend in front of bootstrap class path
-Xdiag            show additional diagnostic messages
-Xnoclassgc       disable class garbage collection
-Xincgc           enable incremental garbage collection
-Xloggc:    log GC status to a file with time stamps
-Xbatch           disable background compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the previous version

Delete .android and AndroidStudioProject files from C:\Users

Install android studio on a different partition

See if it runs on a physical device. Virtualization is needed only for emulators.

Do not import the previous configuration when asked.

Comment: Done. Uninstall Android Studio.